# Breitenlohner-Freedman (BF) stability condition

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, ads-cft, klein-gordon-equation, supergravity

I am looking for a simple way to derive the Breitenlohner-Freedman (BF) bound. Actually I can't understand why we have stability above the BF bound and instability below the BF bound, while both have negative energy so the time dependent part of the filed grow exponentially and it leads to instability?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a quick (and somewhat dirty) way of deriving the bound, do the following: Recall, that in Poincaré coordinates, the metric of $AdS_{d+1}$ is
$$
ds=\frac{1}{z^2}\left(dz^2+\eta^{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu\right).
$$
The equation of motion for a scalar is
$$
(\Box-m^2)\,\phi(z,x)=0,
$$
where $\Box=\frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\partial_a \sqrt{-g}g^{ab}\partial_b$. Plugging in the AdS metric you get
$$
\partial_z^2\phi(z,x)-\frac{d-1}{z}\partial_z \phi(z,x)+z^2\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\partial_\nu\phi(z,x)-\frac{m^2}{z^2}\phi(z,x)=0.
$$
Now, use a plane wave basis for to express the $x$-dependence of the solutions, i.e.
$$
\phi(z,x)=\varphi(z)e^{ik_\mu x^\mu}
$$
Then, the equations of motion become
$$
\partial_z^2\varphi(z)-\frac{d-1}{z}\partial_z\varphi(z)-k_\mu k^\mu \varphi(z)-\frac{m^2}{z^2}\varphi(z)=0
$$
Make the replacement $\varphi(z)\rightarrow z^{\frac{-d+1}{2}}\varphi(z)$
to arrive at
$$
(-\partial_z^2 +V(z))\varphi(z)=\omega^2\varphi(z).
$$
where
$$
V(z)=\vec{k}^2+\frac{1}{z^2}\left(m^2+\frac{d^2-1}{4}\right).
$$
Now, you can use the well-known (?) result that a time dependent Schrödinger equation only admits a stable solution if $V>-\frac{1}{4}$, i.e.
$$
m^2>-\frac{d^2}{4}.
$$

Find details about this last arguement [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4060) and references therein. Another source is this solution to a problem set from a class by Gary Horowitz: web.physics.ucsb.edu/~phys230B/Solution2.pdf

The reason why negative mass$^2$ solutions are allowed is that AdS includes a gravitational potential that gives the negative mass$^2$ eigenstates an overall positive energy.

Comment: Thanks,I have read the references you suggested, in the first reference on the 5th page,it has said that for instability both |si|^2 and " si*dsi " are continuous functions regular at the origin,why it should be like that? I should say that in this paper there is a reference for this last argument but I have no access to that paper.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is right but there is one typo there. The equation that you get after plugging in the AdS metric should not have $z^{2}$ in the third term (i.e. that term should be $\eta^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\partial_{\nu}\phi(z,x)$). However, this mistake is not propagating in the reasoning that follows in the answer above.

Moreover, instead of the stability argument used, one can also use the fact that the differential equation for $\phi(z)$ above can be solved to give $\phi(z)$ in terms of Bessel function and Neumann function. The solution is as follows
$$
\phi(z)=c_{1}\left( \sqrt{z}\;J_{\sqrt{d^{2}+m^{2}}/2}\left( -iz\sqrt{k^{2}-w^{2}}\right)\right)+c_{2}\left( \sqrt{z}\;Y_{\sqrt{d^{2}+m^{2}}/2}\left( -iz\sqrt{k^{2}-w^{2}}\right)\right)
$$
where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are arbitrary coefficients.
Now, if you want the orders of these functions to be real, we need the argument of the square roots to be non-negative and thus, we have
$$
d^{2}+4m^{2}\geq 0\Rightarrow m^{2}\geq -\frac{d^{2}}{4}
$$